# Python Selenium - find in sub-elements

Tags: html, python-3.x, selenium

I have this html:

```html
<ul class="ul_class">
    <li>
        <a>
           ....... 
        </a>
        <div class="my_class">
            <img      class="classA"      src="l1"      data-src="l2"      data-srcset="l3 ad cd el sf dns"      alt="l4"      srcset="l5"> 
        </div>
    </li>
        <li>
        <a>
           ....... 
        </a>
        <div class="my_class">
            <img      class="classA"      src="l1"      data-src="l2"      data-srcset="l3 ad cd el sf dns"      alt="l4"      srcset="l5"> 
        </div>
    </li>
        <li>
        <a>
           ....... 
        </a>
        <div class="my_class">
            <img      class="classA"      src="l1"      data-src="l2"      data-srcset="l3 ad cd el sf dns"      alt="l4"      srcset="l5"> 
        </div>
    </li>
        <li>
        <a>
           ....... 
        </a>
        <div class="my_class">
            <img      class="classA"      src="l1"      data-src="l2"      data-srcset="l3 ad cd el sf dns"      alt="l4"      srcset="l5"> 
        </div>
    </li>
        <li>
        <a>
           ....... 
        </a>
        <div class="my_class">
            <img      class="classA"      src="l1"      data-src="l2"      data-srcset="l3 ad cd el sf dns"      alt="l4"      srcset="l5"> 
        </div>
    </li>
        <li>
        <a>
           ....... 
        </a>
        <div class="my_class">
            <img      class="classA"      src="l1"      data-src="l2"      data-srcset="l3 ad cd el sf dns"      alt="l4"      srcset="l5"> 
        </div>
    </li>

</ul>
```

I want to loop on `li`, and find `data-srcset` value.

Tried this but it is not working:

```
import json, sys
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('http.....')

uls = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("ul_class")
lis = uls.find_elements_by_tag_name('li')
```

How can I loop on `lis`, and for every li find the value of `data-srcset` ?

thanks

***UPDATE***
After I get the first answer I noticed that it was missing something in my question. 
I would like to get an attribute from `<a>` tag and `<img>` tag.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use this selector `ul.ul_class > li > div > img`:

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('ul.ul_class > li > div > img')
for element in elements:
    element.get_attribute("data-srcset")
```

Or if you want use sub-elements strategy, try this approach:

```
uls = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".ul_class")

imgs = uls.find_elements_by_css_selector('li > div > img')
anchors = uls.find_elements_by_css_selector('li > a')

for i in range(len(imgs)):
    print(imgs[i].get_attribute("data-srcset"))
    print(anchors[i].get_attribute("attribute name"))
```

Comment: thanks for your answer I update my question because I want to get to values. One from anchor tag and other from img tag.